# My EMVideoView not show the visualizer

Tags: java, android

I got problem. My EmVideoView not show my custom visualizer
on fragment i use EmVideoView from ExoPlayer.

this is my class with Visualizations

```
    public class VisualizerView extends View {

    private byte[] mBytes;
    private float[] mPoints;
    private Rect mRect = new Rect();
    private Paint mForePaint = new Paint();

    public VisualizerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public VisualizerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public VisualizerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mBytes = null;
        mForePaint.setStrokeWidth(1f);
        mForePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mForePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void updateVisualizer(byte[] bytes) {
        mBytes = bytes;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (mBytes == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (mPoints == null || mPoints.length < mBytes.length * 4) {
            mPoints = new float[mBytes.length * 4];
        }
        mRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < mBytes.length - 1; i++) {
            mPoints[i * 4] = mRect.width() * i / (mBytes.length - 1);
            mPoints[i * 4 + 1] = mRect.height() / 2
                    + ((byte) (mBytes[i] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2) / 128;
            mPoints[i * 4 + 2] = mRect.width() * (i + 1) / (mBytes.length - 1);
            mPoints[i * 4 + 3] = mRect.height() / 2
                    + ((byte) (mBytes[i + 1] + 128)) * (mRect.height() / 2)
                    / 128;
        }
        canvas.drawLines(mPoints, mForePaint);
    }

}
```

and next i create it in xml

```
<com.anta.exoplaytutorial.ui.VisualizerView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/visualizer_view"/>
```

and the last step is initialize and progress in on playing. My code look like:

```
   private void initAudio() {
    setupVisualizerFxAndUI();
    mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);
}

private void setupVisualizerFxAndUI() {


    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(0);
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(
            new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
                public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
                                                  byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
                    visualizerView.updateVisualizer(bytes);
                }

                public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer,
                                             byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {
                }
            }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);
}
```

and i initialize it wit checking permission(also granted) here:

```
 private void playPauseVideo() {
    switch (videoState) {
        case STATUS_PLAYING:
            playVideo();
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)){
                    initAudio();
                }else{
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISIONS_REQUEST
                            );
                }

            }
```

Im not have any errors. Any sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

After clean Project everything works good, so u have simple code for VisualizatorView with getting data from EmVideoView. enjoy

EDIT: if u got information like:

"Cannot initialize Visualization error 1-2-3-4"
is options like
Android 6.0 > runtime permissions called ANDROID M
android 6.0 < permissions AUDIO_RECORD and MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS